# Access a nested variable from nested function

Tags: javascript

```
 <script>
        const counter ={
            cnt: 0,
            inc: function(){
                cnt++;
                console.log(cnt);
            }        
        }
        const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc, false);

    </script>
```

If I run this code as is, I'll get an error of an undefined variable. So I can fix this by adding `couner.cnt` inside of function. However, I don't want to do this. Is there any other way?

Comment: `counter.cnt++`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
const counter = {
    cnt: 0,
    inc: function() {
        this.cnt++;
        console.log(this.cnt);
    }        
}
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
button.addEventListener('click', () => counter.inc(), false);
```

```html
<button name="button">click me</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

No there is no other way unless define global variable outside of the `counter`.

like this:

```js
var cnt = 0;
const counter = {
    inc: function () {
        cnt++;
        console.log(cnt);
    }
}
const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc, false);
```

```html
<button name="button">click me</button>
```

**But** there is better way to do that. You need to use `counter.cnt` instead of `cnt`:

```js
const counter ={
            cnt: 0,
            inc: function(){
                counter.cnt++;
                console.log(counter.cnt);
            }        
        }
        const button = document.getElementsByTagName('button')[0];
        button.addEventListener('click', counter.inc, false);
```

```html
<button name="button">click me</button>
```

Comment: As I wrote before, I don't want to do this. Is there any other option?

Comment: @myfishnameisqwerty what exactly do you want? you need global variable? I mean `cnt` out of the counter? like this: `var cnt = 0;` out of `counter`

Comment: I was wonder If I can access to `cnt` as a variable, but not as a property.

Comment: @myfishnameisqwerty checkout my updated answer. So you need to define it as global variable!!

Comment: Thanks. My main mistake was that I referred to `cnt` as a variable, but not as property.

Comment: @myfishnameisqwerty in the above answer `this` refers to `counter` !! this is second part of my answer! I told you there is no other way

Comment: @myfishnameisqwerty I mean `this` is same as `counter` OK?